# python QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper segsegv

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt

I have built a python app with PyQt4 library.
The app has a graphics scene with a picture on it. I then draw lines over the scene and I catch mouse movements to get the coordinates of the mouse location over the picture.
I attach the mousehover like this:

```
pmItem = QGraphicsPixmapItem(pm, None, self.scene)
pmItem.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
pmItem.hoverMoveEvent = self.pixelSelect
pmItem.hoverLeaveEvent = self.hover_leave
```

The `pixelSelect` method takes the current coordinates and measure the distance to the closest vertical and horizontal lines and draw lines from the current point to theses lines.
And this is the `pixelSelect` method:

```
def pixelSelect(self, event):
        for l in self.v_dist_lines:
            self.scene.removeItem(l)
        self.v_dist_lines = []
        for l in self.h_dist_lines:
            self.scene.removeItem(l)
        self.h_dist_lines = []
        for t in self.txt_dist_list:
            self.scene.removeItem(t)
        self.txt_dist_list = []

        position = QtCore.QPoint(event.pos().x(), event.pos().y())
        closest_h_line, closest_v_line = None, None
        dist_h, dist_v = self.scene_h, self.scene_w
        for l in self.h_lines_list:
            diff = math.fabs(position.y() - l.line().y1())
            if diff < dist_h:
                dist_h = diff
                closest_h_line = l

        for l in self.v_lines_list:
            diff = math.fabs(position.x() - l.line().x1())
            if diff < dist_v:
                dist_v = diff
                closest_v_line = l

        diff_h = round(float(dist_h) / QX11Info.appDpiY() * self.in2cm * (self.draw_scale_y / self.hcm), 2)
        diff_v = round(float(dist_v) / QX11Info.appDpiX() * self.in2cm * (self.draw_scale_x / self.wcm), 2)

        # print(diff_h, diff_v)

        result = ''
        if closest_h_line:
            result += 'Distance to nearest horizontal line is {:0.2f} cm'.format(diff_h)
            result += ',\t'
            self.drawLine(position.x(), position.y(),
                          position.x(), closest_h_line.line().y1(), self.h_dist_lines)
            txt = QGraphicsTextItem(QtCore.QString('{:0.2f}cm'.format(diff_h)),
                                    scene=self.scene)
            txt_x = position.x() + 10
            y_diff = abs(position.y() - closest_h_line.line().y1()) / 2
            txt_y = position.y() + y_diff if closest_h_line.line().y1() > position.y() \
                else position.y() - y_diff
            txt.setPos(QtCore.QPointF(txt_x,
                                      txt_y))
            self.txt_dist_list.append(txt)
        if closest_v_line:
            result += 'Distance to nearest vertical line is {:0.2f} cm'.format(diff_v)
            self.drawLine(position.x(), position.y(),
                          closest_v_line.line().x1(), position.y(), self.v_dist_lines)
            txt = QGraphicsTextItem(QtCore.QString('{:0.2f}cm'.format(diff_v)),
                                    scene=self.scene)
            x_diff = abs(position.x() - closest_v_line.line().x1()) / 2
            txt_x = position.x() + x_diff if closest_h_line.line().x1() > position.x() \
                else position.x() - x_diff
            txt_y = position.y() + 10
            txt.setPos(QtCore.QPointF(txt_x,
                                      txt_y))
            self.txt_dist_list.append(txt)

        self.statusBar().showMessage(result)
```

When I run the app, it runs perfect for a few seconds (sometimes with the very first mouse movement) then it crashes while I'm moving the cursor inside the scene. I noticed it doesn't crash when there are no lines drawn over the scene. The method `pixelSelect` is still running even if there are no lines so I don't think that the problem is in the method.
When I debugged using `gdb`, I got this when I ran the porgram:

> Starting program: /usr/bin/python main.py [Thread debugging using
>   libthread_db enabled]
>   Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
>   [New Thread 0x7fffe4048700 (LWP 9767)]
>   [New Thread 0x7fffe3847700 (LWP 9768)]
>   [New Thread 0x7fffe3046700 (LWP 9769)]
>   [New Thread 0x7fffd3fff700 (LWP 9770)]
>   [New Thread 0x7fffd37fe700 (LWP 9771)]
>   [Thread 0x7fffd3fff700 (LWP 9770) exited]
>   [New Thread 0x7fffd3fff700 (LWP 9792)]
>   [New Thread 0x7fffcbfff700 (LWP 9793)]
>   [New Thread 0x7fffcb7fe700 (LWP 9794)]
>   [New Thread 0x7fffcaffd700 (LWP 9795)]
>   [Thread 0x7fffd3fff700 (LWP 9792) exited]
>   [Thread 0x7fffcb7fe700 (LWP 9794) exited]
>   [Thread 0x7fffcbfff700 (LWP 9793) exited]
>   [Thread 0x7fffcaffd700 (LWP 9795) exited]
>   [Thread 0x7fffd37fe700 (LWP 9771) exited]

and when it crashes this is the output of the `bt`:

> Thread 1 "python" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
>   (gdb) bt
>   0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
>   1  0x00007ffff3d28fdc in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
>   2  0x00007ffff3d2ff16 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) ()    from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
>   3  0x00007ffff4e15f56 in ?? ()    from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
>   4  0x00007ffff636790d in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
>   5  0x00007ffff434884d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
>   6  0x00007ffff4350b91 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
>   7  0x00007ffff4350f1f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
>   8  0x00007ffff435146a in QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
>   9  0x00007ffff4cd839b in ?? ()    from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
>   10 0x00007ffff435e607 in QGraphicsScene::event(QEvent*) ()    from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
>   11 0x00007ffff4cd9c6b in ?? ()    from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
>   12 0x00007ffff3d28fdc in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
>   13 0x00007ffff3d2ff16 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
>   ---Type return to continue, or q return to quit---

So, it is something with `QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper` method. Can any one help with this problem? 
I know it is a `SEGSEGV` error which means memory issues. But the same code runs the same way all the time on the same data. But it crashes in different times with different cases which makes it difficult to know what is abusing the memory.

## UPDATE

I added the code to a github repo:
https://github.com/Ahmedn1/Image_Splitter

Comment: you could share the complete code through github or gist so you can test it since testing your current code is difficult.

Comment: @eyllanesc here it is https://github.com/Ahmedn1/Image_Splitter

Comment: Change `self.scene = QGraphicsScene()` to `self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)`

Comment: Changed it but it still crashes with the same trace. @eyllanesc

Comment: It is not recommended to use gdb with python, I have executed with that modification, load an image and close the window without errors, before making that modification the window closed with errors.

Comment: Did you add lines over the image and try to hover for a few seconds?

Comment: I could never add lines. Your code is not structured correctly and is not readable so do not try

Comment: Just specify the number of lines in the respective text boxes and hit submit